# How do I deliver voltage to a coil in arduino

Tags: arduino, voltage

I'm working on a project to allow me to launch fireworks using my TV remote IR control. 
If I wrap a 28ga wire into a coil and connect it to a battery it gets red-hot and works as my fuse igniter. 
[image]
But I can't get this to work with my Arduino.
[image]

When I measure voltage without the coil, I can see that my 4.5V are getting delivered to where the coil gets hooked up. 
But when I connect the coil and send power to the coil (`digitalWrite(2, HIGH);`),the voltage reads very low .5v or something like that.

**How can I deliver the 4.5v to my coils?** What am I missing? A diode, transistor?

[Here is the fritzing file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0hEcZdV8bW7N0w0alI5WUlZWmc) in case you'd like to modify it and add the missing component(s).

I apologize in advance, I never took any electronics classes so electronics jargon might be lost on me.

UPDATE RESULTS:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aL8SLlF6JM

Comment: Do you really expect a wire to get red hot no matter what voltage source you connect it to?

Comment: @Dmitry Do you really expect someone to expect such a thing? Document says it puts out 5v on signal. It would be enough. What the velros documents failed to mention was the very low current.

Comment: If 5V would be enough, why does your picture show a 9V battery?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev 9V powers the Arduino and it's 5V regulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot power a coil directly from the GPIO of the Arduino. The ATMEGA at its heart can only do 40 mA max from a GPIO,  and that's with significant voltage droop from its internal ESR. Like a resistor in series. You quite possibly damaged the pin or port or whole arduino doing this. Since a coil is a few ohms or less, you are trying to pull AMPS through it.

What you need is a coil driver circuit. Easy enough with a NPN transistor. First measure the resistance of the coil. Then divide the voltage through the coil by its resistance. If we wire it to 9V, and it has a resistance of 2 ohm, it will try to pull 4.5 Amps. This is why the coil gets hot. It will also drain the 9V battery super quick.

Then you need a transistor that can handle that load. While also being able to turn on from 20mA at its base. So it needs a HFE or gain of 300 minimum. Not likely for your setup. Instead, you may have to resort to using a relay. Since a relay is also just a coil, the driver is still needed. A common 2n3904 transistor will handle most small relays.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3lJsS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Three setups. The first is a simple NPN, but finding one with the right gain and current load capability may be hard. The second adds a relay instead. It could be powered from the Arduino's 5V rail instead leaving the 9V for the e-fuse. This makes the driver transistor easy. A common 2n3904 and any small relay works.

The last may be easiest. A logic level mosfet with a load capacity of 10 Amps would be just fine here. A bit harder to find but simpler to use. The R4 is a safety feature, a pull-down to make sure it doesn't activate while the Arduino goes through its setup and the GPIO is in input mode.

Comment: Also, many 9V batteries aren't capable of supplying more than a few hundred mA, so if Amps are needed, might want to change the power source.

Comment: @wesley true. But OP has tested it and it has worked as an e-fuse at the moment so I assume it's sufficient for now.

Comment: @passerby The OP knows little to nothing about electronics...why confuse further with complexities. Draw a block diagram.

Comment: @jack on mobile, can't right now.

Comment: @Passerby In the end I went with the relay to make it easier on myself. decided to short the coil just like a mechanical vaping mod does for 2 seconds. Thanks for your help! results: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aL8SLlF6JM

Comment: @capdragon glad to hear. Firework igniter systems are great.

Comment: @Passerby of course i'm going to give an update after the 4th of July. Worked flawlessly. All fired every time. I added 4 more cannons for a total of 16. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRLOCg0uV4M

Answer (score 0):

Estes makes squibs for their rocket engines. Their all-fire specification (I got this by personally speaking with their senior engineer) is to deliver \$\frac{1}{2}\:\textrm{J}\$ in \$50\:\textrm{ms}\$ into a resistance (the squib) of about \$\frac{2}{3}\:\Omega\$. This requires an average of \$2.6\:\textrm{V}\$ at the squib, though a discharge curve is just fine, of course.

However, the above also suggests an average of \$3.9\:\textrm{A}\$. Which isn't something that you come by easily out in the field. Especially with a typical \$9\:\textrm{V}\$ battery.

---

None of the above necessarily applies to your case. The Estes squib also includes a small bit of easily ignited oxidizer/reducer compound (not sure if it is a dried black powder paste [don't think so] or something else.) You are just using a bit of wire, which I consider to be a little less reliable here. But I have to take you at your word that it works with a \$9\:\textrm{V}\$ battery, though I'm having a hard time believing that you've tested it successfully. I believe it gets hot. But I'm having a hard time believing it actually works in the field with real fireworks. I believe you are projecting a personal sensation of "very hot" and imagining that it will work in the field.

---

Now you have the context of my thoughts. Here's the rest.

I think you need to be absolutely certain that your wire will produce results. This means it must ignite your fireworks every time you ask it to do so. You must understand and describe your "all fire" specification -- which you must develop. You've shown none of that, so far. So this means it is really impossible to provide you with a safe and operating circuit that will reliably provide the operation you want. We don't have the information needed.

Certainly, there is no question in my mind that the Arduino I/O pins are woefully incapable of heating up a firing mechanism like this. So that's out. We could suggest that you use transistors in some circuit, with a power source having an appropriate current compliance as well, to do the job. But we really don't know what that is. It's going to be true that there is some minimum voltage and some minimum current (assuming constant, average values delivered) to get the job done. But how is it possible to know that, given what you've said? We could assume that your conviction that a \$9\:\textrm{V}\$ battery really does do the job. But I'm frankly not yet convinced it does. So you'd need to address yourself to that detail, first.

One could also consider the idea of drawing power at a rate that a \$9\:\textrm{V}\$ battery can consistently provide (not so much) and to accumulate that as energy on a capacitor for later discharge. This would be a more complex circuit, and it would not give you "instant fire" capability since it would take time to develop the necessary ready-energy (you'd have to wait for a few moments between events.) But it could allow such a battery to do the job, reliably. And it could be designed to be triggered by an Arduino, as well. But if you have access to a separate Arduino power supply, why not use that instead of the \$9\:\textrm{V}\$ battery? It likely has more current compliance. And given the bit of wire, it's likely (but we still lack the info here) that the required voltage can do the job.

---

I'd like to see more thoughtfulness on your part about the "all fire" specification and I'd want you to confirm that you've actually used your battery + wire in a real situation with the actual fireworks you intend on using. This whole area has matters of safety associated with it. (What happens if the fireworks doesn't ignite? Do you walk over and "see what's wrong?" Perhaps there will be a delayed firing and you have no idea about that and get hurt?) It's important that you know exactly what works, each time, and every time.

If I were approaching this I'd be thinking about many different issues and carefully thinking through the detailed implications of each.

1. How consistently can I make a firing squib out of wire? What's the variations on the pieces I actually can make?
2. What is my "all fire" specification?
3. Use commercial equipment that will meet my all fire spec and then test squibs with some kind of test fragment of fireworks which will convince me that it does work correctly, each time and every time.
4. What is my power source? Am I seriously going to require both a \$5\:\textrm{V}\$ and a \$9\:\textrm{V}\$ power source? Why? What is the best power source for my application and how does that set the stage for the rest?
5. What safety factors, both technical and human procedure, do I need to support? This may include maximum voltages and alarm lights and arming procedures, etc.
6. How far away will by firing circuit be from the actual fireworks? Should I divide it up into two parts, separated by wiring, with one part near the fireworks and one part to trigger it from a distance? (Is this why you have two power supplies? You didn't say.)

And there's more, of course, that will arise as you work through the details.

I would have liked to see you talk about all this to provide context here. But on the technical side, there's no all-fire specification and I'm not convinced by your wording so far that what you write about actually does the job, reliably.

Comment: A fresh 9V alkaline battery will put out amperes. Try it on the 20A scale of your multimeter. Do **not** try a rechargable NiCd 9V- they have been known to violently explode.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I'm not saying it won't (I have not tried it, though.) I just wouldn't design for that. Which is the point.

Comment: Yes, it absolutely works with the fireworks. I made [another controller](https://goo.gl/yVg7FU) which was simply a series of switches hooked up to a battery. It worked every time flawlessly. I just wanted to make it better because it required long cat5 cables to be run to the [launchpad](https://goo.gl/cmGH3q).

Comment: @capdragon I'm glad you've written to confirm it works. But now you've added the cat5 cable part. All of this should have been in the question at the outset. I assume your controller is at one end and the 9 V battery at the other end, near the fireworks? (Regardless, I wish you'd provided a lot more detail.) Thanks for the update, though.

Comment: I think OP is going for a remote controlled solution, where those wires wouldn't be needed. The Arduino,  battery and coil would all be at the launch pad.

Comment: @Passerby Hmm. I wish we did less presumption and the OP did more writing. One of these days...

Comment: @capdragon actually that is a good question. Keep in mind that extra long cables will have their own resistance and cause a voltage drop equal to the current being pulled. I'm assuming the battery and coil are physically close. Am I right?